# DiffUtil.ItemCallback areItemsTheSame() method check items twice

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils, android-paging-3

I send request to [/list.php?page=1](http://#) and display data in UI with Paging 3 component.

In first request, **areItemsTheSame(new, old)** method do nothing. No log in Logcat.

Then i refresh data with SwipeRefreshLayout and request sent same api (/list.php?page=1).

DiffUtil.ItemCallback **areItemsTheSame(new, old)** method check items twice. once in descending order then ascending order.

Logcat:

> I: newItem: 3308 = oldItem: 3308
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3307 = oldItem: 3307
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3306 = oldItem: 3306
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3305 = oldItem: 3305
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3304 = oldItem: 3304
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3303 = oldItem: 3303
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3302 = oldItem: 3302
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3301 = oldItem: 3301
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3300 = oldItem: 3300
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3300 = oldItem: 3300
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3301 = oldItem: 3301
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3302 = oldItem: 3302
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3303 = oldItem: 3303
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3304 = oldItem: 3304
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3305 = oldItem: 3305
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3306 = oldItem: 3306
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3307 = oldItem: 3307
> I: check: true
> I: newItem: 3308 = oldItem: 3308
> I: check: true

VacancyFragment:
[image]

Adapter:
[image]

ViewModel:
[image]

DataSource:
[image]

Comment: please, post the full code of update method (ie exact place where you call diff util)

Comment: I added VacancyFragment, Adapter, ViewModel and DataSource code

Comment: areContentsTheSame() method check once

Comment: `submitData` & `refresh` methods too, if you don't mind

Comment: submit and refresh methods are built-in methods.

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay attention it's `PagingAdapter`, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i found the answer.

> Myers's algorithm does not handle items that are moved so DiffUtil
> runs a second pass on the result to detect items that were moved.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil